# Is there a good tool to duplicate a tree of related records in a relational database?

Tags: mysql, database, frameworks

I have an application requirement to duplicate data that spans multiple MySQL database tables. The primary keys are unique auto incremented ids. The foreign keys have to be managed during the insert.

To illustrate the problem, say we have a three tier hierarchy: department, employee and task. A department has many employees, and each employee has many tasks. To duplicate an entire department, we need to

- insert the department, get the new pk
- for each employee, insert it with new department pk, get the employee pk
- for each task, insert it with the employee pk

I'd like to use some metadata / configuration driven framework in java or python. Any ideas?

Comment: I've never encountered a general-use tool to do this, only sometimes I've seen custom-made scripts for one application. This makes sense, because there are too many variations between applications. A tool that could be reusable for _any_ application would be so complex to use that it would practically be easier to code a one-off solution for your own application.

Comment: I posted that as a comment instead of as an answer, because Stack Overflow's [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) discourage questions asking for tool recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, bog-standard JPA is the normal way to do this, it should be quite straightforward. You have 3 entities and the relationships are established exactly as you describe, with a OneToMany from dept to employee and another from employee to task.

JPA can do the whole thing for you soup to nuts, including building the database schema, etc.

You could use other techniques if you don't like ORMs (I don't like them myself) such as this library https://openhms.sourceforge.io/sqlbuilder/ but it will require doing some things yourself that JPA 'automagically' handles (or mishandles depending on how you look at it...).

Comment: The ORM does abstract sql generation, but it’s not handling the core copy/duplication challenge in a generic way. IMO this seems to me essentially a proprietary coded solution. For example I write the code to copy the dept-employee-tasks but I can’t use it for the dept-purchase orders-items, or whathaveyou.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't expect this to be something you would CODE. There are, as one of the commenters on your question pointed out, a WIDE variety of ETL tools out there. Depending on the brand of RDBMS in use, and many other factors such as the volume of data, frequency of updates, and exact replication requirements, a lot of options exist. You could also explore database replication, ALMOST all modern RDBMS can handle doing that, though some require expensive licenses and such.

Comment: Thanks Tod. I did look into a couple of ETL tools, e.g. springer. Seems focused on data integration, ongoing feeds, replication and the like. They aren't a good fit. In my context, a user request drives duplication of a specific set of data objects, back into the same database, and the same tables.